# Cost of using select() in different threads for the same process

Tags: c, select

In my application, I'm starting to use the `select()` call in multiple locations, monitoring different things in my process (network connections, IPCs, messaging, files...).
All the calls are using their *own* set of file descriptors, meaning no descriptor is used twice across selects.

This means that some times, I have something like 5 `select()` calls blocking in different threads.

Is there a performance penalty of using `select()` multiple times in different threads, instead of, maybe, using only *one* call and dispatching results to the corresponding threads?

Actually, is there a limit to the number of `select()` calls pending at one time?

Is there a tool to measure this?

Since the application is likely to grow even bigger, I suspect that at some point, if this begins to get problematic, I'll have to code some kind of centralized `select()` which gathers all FDs to monitor and notifies client threads when data is ready to be gathered/written.

So I figured I'd better ask before...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is unlikely to be any performance difference you will notice.

Inside the kernel, `select` adds your thread to a "wait queue" for each descriptor on which you are selecting and puts it to sleep.  If you select on `n` descriptors, your thread gets added to `n` wait queues.  When something pollable happens to the descriptor (e.g., data arrives on the socket), all threads on that wait queue get woken up.

Selecting on a huge number of descriptors would add you to a huge number of wait queues.  Once woken up, your thread will have to be removed from all of those wait queues, including the ones on which there was no activity.  So on this side, there might be some slight benefit to waiting on a small set of descriptors in multiple threads rather than a huge set of descriptors in one thread.

On the other hand, `select` itself requires that the kernel loop through *all possible descriptors* to see which ones are a member of your `fd_set`.  So on this side, there might be some slight advantage to having just one thread making the `select` call...

Overall I would guess it is a wash.

If you are going to deal with a lot of descriptors, you are better off using a more scalable (albeit non-portable) mechanism like `epoll`.  With `epoll`, multiple threads each handling a pool of descriptors should scale very nicely.

Comment: Nice answer, quite complete also. I'll take it!

Comment: The "on the other hand" is rather irrelevant. Looping through 1024 **bits** is hardly a loop at all. That's just 128 bytes.

Comment: Also note that `epoll` will be considerably *slower* than select/poll if you have to add/remove file descriptors from the set frequently, since that takes an extra syscall (user-kernel-user transition). It only makes sense when you have long term stability in the set of file descriptors in use.

Comment: @R: I am pretty sure `epoll` is what the fastest Web servers on the planet use.  If your network protocol does less per connection than HTTP, then your network protocol needs a redesign.  (Like HTTP itself did with Keep-Alive connections...)  Point being, your polling should be orders of magnitude more frequent than adding/removing descriptors from the set; otherwise, you are not talking about high performance anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The select call should be handled in the OS, and as you said - its blocking, not polling - so it won't cause a performance penalty on your application.  I also do not believe there will be any limits on using it aside from any limits on the amount of file descriptors your OS can have open in general, which has nothing to do with select.